# Follow up questions referencing their origin

Tags: discussion

When posting a question that uses a previous question or answer as a premise, is just [linking the question/answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/583/how-would-the-design-of-an-underground-castle-differ) good enough, or should we [quote the question/answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/339/what-would-a-planet-spinning-fast-enough-to-allow-geostationary-orbit-near-the-s?rq=1) as well? If the latter, how much quoting is too much?

Answer (score 11):

If the context contained in the body of the question/answer is relavant to what you are asking then it makes sense to quote the important part.  If the reference is just to inform why you are asking the question but contains no important context then there is no real reason to quote it.

The goal is to provide great context but also only the details that are actually needed for the question.  If you provide details that do not matter people tend to focus on the wrong things in the quote rather than what you are asking about.